# How to not return duplicates when comparing records in same table (A:B and B:A)

Tags: sql, duplicates, oracle-sqldeveloper, with-statement

I have been stuck with this problem for a while now and can't resolve it, would greatly appreciate some guidance

I am comparing records in a persons table to see if they're possibly the same. To do this I am using a with statement to take the values I need and looking for matches

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
  serialno VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  given VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  family  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  dob  DATE NOT NULL,
  gender VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  address VARCHAR2(64 BYTE)
);

INSERT ALL 
    INTO persons ( serialno, given, family,dob,gender,address ) VALUES ( '001', 'Mick', 'Dundon','01/01/1970','Male','Main St' )
    INTO persons ( serialno, given, family, dob,gender,address) VALUES ( '002', 'Mick', 'Dundon','01/01/1970', 'Male','Montague St' )
    INTO persons ( serialno, given, family,dob,gender,address ) VALUES ( '003', 'Dave', 'Doyle', '13/10/1981','Male', 'Rathmines')
    INTO persons ( serialno, given, family,dob,gender,address ) VALUES ( '004', 'Jim', 'Morrison', '15/08/1956','Male','Newtown')
    INTO persons ( serialno, given, family, dob,gender,address) VALUES ( '005', 'Sam', 'Wise', '12/12/1992','Male','High St')
SELECT 1 FROM dual;

with rec as
(select serialno,given,family,dob,gender,address 
from persons)
select * 
from rec r1
join rec r2
on r1.given = r2.given
and r1.family = r2.family
and r1.gender = r2.gender
and r1.serialno <> r2.serialno
```

the code works fine except I end up with duplicates as the R1 record will appear further down in the output as R2, and vice versa.
Is there a simple way I can avoid this kind of duplication?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Simply `r1.serial < r2.serial`?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Comment: @jarlh yes, sorry i should have provided an example. i've done that noe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the duplicates without a self-join by using the analytic `COUNT` function:

```sql
SELECT serialno, given, family, dob, gender, address
FROM   (
  SELECT serialno, given, family, dob, gender, address,
         COUNT(*)  OVER (PARTITION BY given, family, gender) AS num_matches
  FROM   persons
)
WHERE num_matches > 1;
```

---

If you also want to compare the values to the row with the same `given`/`family`/`gender` combination and the minimum serial number then, again you can avoid a self-join by using analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT serialno, given, family, dob, gender, address,
       min_serialno, min_dob, min_address
FROM   (
  SELECT serialno,
         given,
         family,
         dob,
         gender,
         address,
         MIN(serialno) OVER (PARTITION BY given, family, gender) AS min_serialno,
         MIN(dob) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY serialno)
           OVER (PARTITION BY given, family, gender) AS min_dob,
         MIN(address) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY serialno)
           OVER (PARTITION BY given, family, gender) AS min_address
  FROM   persons
)
WHERE serialno > min_serialno;
```

---

If, in Oracle, you want to get all possible combinations then you can avoid a self-join by using a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT serialno, given, family, dob, gender, address,
       PRIOR serialno AS p_serialno,
       PRIOR dob      AS p_dob,
       PRIOR address  AS p_address
FROM   persons
WHERE  LEVEL = 2
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR gender   = gender
AND    PRIOR given    = given
AND    PRIOR family   = family
AND    PRIOR serialno < serialno
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=24d88a983377f80f4d1a953a6118616b)*